# Retrieving and AWS Glacier Archive via CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier, qnap

I'm using the AWS CLI to try to retrieve an AWS Archive that was pushed to Glacier via a QNAP NAS backup task.   I've successfully initiated the download `aws glacier initiate-job --account-id` etc, and have got my inventory file `aws glacier get-job-output --account-id`.

However the file that's downloaded shows 19,000+ `ArchiveId`s, which is appears to be an `ArchiveId` for each file.

I understand that as part of the `aws glacier initiate-job` command I have to send a json file containing information such as:

```
{
  "Type": "archive-retrieval",
  "ArchiveId": "2CTtNlWpf6PdtDIH62Zy",
  "Description": "Download 2017 photos archive"
}
```

Is there a way I can programatically download all of these archives?  For example can I include them all in the JSON file I send?

Comment: If you need to iterate over a large dataset like this, it may make more sense to use an AWS SDK, such as Boto3 for Python which will allow you to wrap the equivalent API calls in SDK calls within loops.

Comment: Using Amazon Glacier directly is very difficult. I recommend using a tool like [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/) to access the archives.

Comment: Thanks guys. After an hour or two I just decided to buy Freeze for Mac.  Works a charm :)